# what does $\ltimes$ in the context of representation theory mean?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am considering the following sentence wich is part of a theorem:

'' Let $V$ be a finite dimensional unitary representation of $H=\mathbb{Z}^{2} \rtimes $ SL$_2(\mathbb{Z})$."

I have no background in represantion theory but i know what a unitary representation of a group is. What does the symbol $\rtimes$ mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the notation for *semidirect product* - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product.

Answer (score 1):

All this is saying is that $H$ (as a group) is the [semidirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) product of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. It isn't really about the representation.